# Hooks parent unmounted before children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I' working on react since few months. I started Hooks since few days (I know quite late) the thing is, compare to react component the life cycle methodes it's look like they are different on some points.

The useEffect hook can reproduce :

```
-componentDidMount();
-componentDidUpdate();
-componentWillUnMount();
```

But I observe a difference between react's component and function it's about the way how function is unmounted. I noted the unmount methode, compare to the react's component,the react's function unmount the parent before the child/ren

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
 
export function Child2({
  count,
  childrenUnmounted,
}: {
  count: number;
  childrenUnmounted: Function;
}): ReactElement {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("Unmounted");
      childrenUnmounted(count);
    };
  }, [, count]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Unmouted</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Child1({ count }: { count: number }): ReactElement {
  const [validation, setValidation] = useState(false);
  const usehistory = useHistory();
  const childrenUnmounted = (count: number) => {
    console.log("validation", validation, count);
    setValidation(false);
  };

  const changeUrl = () => {
    setValidation(true);
    usehistory.push("http://localhost:3000/${count}");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>incremente</h2>
      <Child2
        count={count}
        childrenUnmounted={(count: number) => childrenUnmounted(count)}
      />
      <button className="button" onClick={() => changeUrl()}>
        validation
      </button>
      <button
        className="button"
        onClick={() => usehistory.push(`http://localhost:3000/${count}`)}
      >
        nope
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Parent(): ReactElement {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(-1);
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    setcount(count + 1);
  }, [, location]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>hello</h2>
      <h3>{count}</h3>
      <Child1 count={count} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

With the code above something annoying happen, when you clicked on the `validation` button. Value in the `Child1`is at `true`, at the moment of the click, and it's change the `URL` to trigger a rerender of the `Parent` to change the data (here count).

The thing I don't understand is why at the unmount of the Child2, at the childrenUnmounted(count) called (to trigger the same function but in the Child1) in the Child1 the validation is equal to `false` even the validation was clicked ? and when you click on `nope` just after validation you got true... it's look like the Child1 do not matter of the current state of the `validation` (he use the previous state)

Someone could help me to understand what's going on ?
Thx of the help.

---

---

SOLUTION:

I used useRef instead of useState from the validation to don't depend of the re-render as `Giovanni Esposito`  said :

> because hooks are async and you could not get the last value setted for state

So useRef was my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I think you problem is related on **when** you logs `validation` value. I explain better.

Your parent relationship are: Parent -> Child1 -> Child2. Ok.

Now you click `validation` button on Child2. `validation` button calls `changeUrl` that calls `usehistory.push("http://localhost:3000/${count}");` and **starts to change `validation` value** (why starts? because `setValidation` is async).

If the unmounting of Child2 comes now, could be that `validation` value is no yet setted by async `setValidation` (and log returns the old value for `validation`).

Well, at some point this `setValidation` finished and sets `validation` to true. Now you click `nope` button and you get true for `validation` (the last value setted).

So, to make the story short, I think that what you are seeing in logs it's just because hooks are async and you could not get the last value setted for state (if you use log in this way). The only way you have to log always the last value setted is `useEffect` hook with value you want to log in deps list.

Comment: Yes you right! At least I found a solution to counter this. If I use useRef instead of useState from the validation, I can use the value directly  because useRef no need a re-render to modify the value ;) thx

Comment: Very happy to ear that. If you found this answer useful, please mark as valid. Have a nice day :)